# TCP Socket keep alive in WCF application

Tags: web-services, wcf, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to keep a TCP connection alive in WCF appliction. The architecture is like one linux server(3rd party) and I have no rights to change modify any thing. WCF service on IIS and android Client. Now the process flow is clients requests data from WCF, WCF create a TCP connection with 3rd party server fetches the data and sends it to the client(android) and closes the socket. This flow works fine when you have limited users requesting at same time. But due to time the number of user are increased to hundreds and thousands. And most of the users are complaining about the requests are beings discarded with message "Remote host not available." This is custom message which i have defined when the third party server rejects the TCP connection. 3rd party server entertains lets say 100 requests in one minute and if the request limit exceeds then it simply rejects it. Have talked to the 3rd party server owner, and as per their saying we have to create one TCP socket and send as many request as we can and it will not reject the requests. And can also send heartbeat message when there are no requests. Now my question is how can I keep the TCP connection open and keep alive 24/7 with heart beat message using the WCF application. As the WCF application becomes active when and only any request is received, how can I make it running like a console application or windows service so that the connection would not be closed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.